# How to validate a UITextField in a CustomCell after scrolling down to tap the button to Continue to the next screen - Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell, dynamic-tables

I have a `Dynamic Table` with several `UITextFields` in `Custom Cells`. However, when I scroll to the bottom of the `TableView` and tap on the Continue button I am having issues getting the `text` of the `UITextFields` that are out of the screen after scrolling. In other words, I get the error

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.**

when I try to get the `text` for the `Street Address Text Field` which is outside of the screen once I have scrolled down to the bottom of the screen to tap the Continue button.

***Table View Controller:***

```
class RNSContactInfoTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            //static street address cell
            let streetAddressCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("streetAddressCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StreetAddressCell
            setStreetAddressTextFieldValue(streetAddressCell)
            return streetAddressCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            //static apt or suite cell
            let aptOrSuiteCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("aptOrSuiteCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AptOrSuiteCell
            setAptOrSuiteTextFieldValue(aptOrSuiteCell)
            return aptOrSuiteCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            //static city cell
            let cityCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CityCell
            setCityTextFieldValue(cityCell)
            return cityCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            //static state cell
            let stateCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("stateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StateCell
            setStateTextFieldValue(stateCell)
            return stateCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 4) {
            //static zip code cell
            let zipcodeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("zipcodeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ZipCodeCell
            setZipcodeTextFieldValue(zipcodeCell)
            return zipcodeCell
        } else {
            //default cell
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            return cell
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: Button Tapped Methods
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    @IBAction func reviewServiceOrderButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        //Dismiss keyboard when button is tapped
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        //Set user fields
        //<==========THE LINE BELOW IS CRASHING============>
        let streetAddressCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)) as! StreetAddressCell
        //<================================================>
        let streetAddressStr = streetAddressCell.streetAddressTextField.text

        let aptOrSuiteCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 0)) as! AptOrSuiteCell
        let aptOrSuiteStr = aptOrSuiteCell.aptOrSuiteTextField.text

        let cityCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 6, inSection: 0)) as! CityCell
        let cityStr = cityCell.cityTextField.text

        let stateCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 7, inSection: 0)) as! StateCell
        let stateStr = stateCell.stateTextField.text

        let zipcodeCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 8, inSection: 0)) as! ZipCodeCell
        let zipcodeStr = zipcodeCell.zipcodeTextField.text

        // Check for empty fields
        if (streetAddressStr!.isEmpty || cityStr!.isEmpty || stateStr!.isEmpty || zipcodeStr!.isEmpty || firstNameStr!.isEmpty || lastNameStr!.isEmpty || emailStr!.isEmpty || phoneAreaCodeStr!.isEmpty || phonePrefixStr!.isEmpty || phoneLineNumberStr!.isEmpty)
        {
            // Display error message
            self.displayAlertMessage(EMPTY_REQUIRED_FIELDS_ERROR_TITTLE, message: EMPTY_REQUIRED_FIELDS_ERROR_MESSAGE)
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're finding out, one of the things that `UITableView` does is release `UITableViewCell`s that are not currently displayed.  Part of that means that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will return `nil` for cells that aren't currently visible.

You'll need to extract the data from the cells as it is changed (see the various `UITextFieldDelegate` methods) and before the cell is scrolled off screen instead of trying to find the cell itself later.

Not relevant to this particular question, but also of note is that it will reuse cells of the same type as you scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `textField.delegate = self`

and:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Here you need to save your UITextField values in a property or a reference where you want to keep it when the user changes the text. And when pressing the `Next` button you can get the values from the property instead, not the textField as you are trying to do now.

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

}
```

If you have many fields, an `NSDictionary` would be preferred.